# SQL - Get "exact" Father Match by Children

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

#### Father

```
ID
------
a
b
c
```

#### Child

```
f_ID    ID
------------
a        1
a        2
a        3
b        1
b        2
c        1
```

I want to :

- Get "a" when I give [1, 2, 3]
- Get "b" when I give [1, 2]
- Get "c" when I give [1]

The problem is if I use

```
SELECT *    
FROM Father AS F    
INNER JOIN Child AS C    
ON C.f_ID = F.ID    
WHERE C.ID IN ( '1' )
```

This will give me fathers : 1, 2, 3

Please help, I'm new to SQL

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.  I just tacked an "and not exists" on to the end of your Where clause.

```
SELECT * Father AS F
INNER JOIN Child AS C
    ON C.f_ID = F.ID
WHERE C.ID IN ( '1' )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Child
    WHERE Child.ID NOT IN ('1')
    AND F.ID = Child.f_ID
)
```

As an alternative method, you could self-join and select for the null rows.

```
SELECT * Father AS F
INNER JOIN Child AS C
    ON C.f_ID = F.ID AND C.ID IN ( '1' )
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT f_ID FROM Child WHERE ID NOT IN ('1')) a
    ON C.f_ID = a.f_ID
WHERE a.f_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: looks like this does not work ether
if i query ... WHERE .... ('1', '2') then there will be 2 results.

i need sort of EXCAT MATCH is i mentioned under "I want to :"

Answer (score 0):

To be able to match whole sequences you need to count matches and compare it to count of given sequence:

```
select f.f_id
  from father f
 inner join child c
    on f.f_id = c.f_id
 -- exact sequence given
 where c.f_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by f_id
-- compare number of children to number of elements in parameter sequence
having count (distinct c.c_id) = 3
```

Comment: if i insert a record in Child table ['b', '3'] there will be 2 results matching count 3

Comment: Exactly. Children 1,2,3 will have two fathers. Which one would you choose?

Comment: correct, so my problem is more deep, i'm not well instructed about the full picture. will be back soon !